# Spring Boot + Security: How to redirect to unauthenticated index.html

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I build a small API with Spring Boot. For authentication and authorization I use Spring security together with Keycloak.
My current problem is, that I want to show a static index.html giving some Info about the API, when `http://myserver:8080` is opened. The index.html is there and can be accessed with `http://myserver:8080/index.html`. However, when just opening `http://myserver:8080` the request is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/auth/`.
My questions are:

1. How can I redirect any request from the root `http://localhost:8080/*` to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`?
2. What would be a reasonable HttpSecurity configuration?
   I want to grand access without authentication to the root /*, but I want to require authentification for all subfolders such as /api/*. I tried the following which does not seem correct.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: where is your index.html is stored? Springboot by defaults look for `static content locations` in static content locations which is your `/resources/` path. Place your index.html there and it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! It was stored in /resources/static/index.hmtl. It works in /resources. Do you want to propose an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked for you, added more information to the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default spring boot looks for static content files and directories that are on the classpath as below

1. /static/
2. /public/
3. /resources/
4. /META-INF/resources

So, If you want to access `index.html` either it should be present in the classpath or you need to `configure the location`. So, that spring boot is aware about the location.

If you want to configure the location present in the classpath

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/files/
```

or if you want to configure the location outside of classpath then also you can do soething like below,

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:<path_to_file>
```

**Reference:**
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot